# Why does my table have a random space to the side?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a responsive table, but for some reason when I stack the cells 1x3, the entire table has a random bit of space on the left side. I can't seem to figure out why...

https://codepen.io/asyi/pen/ybjOJa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
        <title>DateNight Table 1 x 3</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Clicker+Script|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="info-table">
            <div id="table-1" class="table-display">
                <img src="images/search_transparent.png" alt="">
                <h1 class="blue-title"> Best Babysitters in Town </h1>
                <p class="blue-text"> We are serious about having only amazing babysitters on our
                roster. They've all been Skype interviewed by a parent, have 1-2
                years of experience and can provide 2 childcare-related references.
                Our parent approval rate is through the roof. University and
                College students, long-time babysitters, ECE students. Only the best.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="table-2" class="table-display">
                <img src="images/search_transparent.png" alt="">
                <h1 class="white-title"> This is Easy </h1>
                <p class="white-text"> We're parents, too. We know how short on time you are.
                DateNight gives parents a small pool of great candidates from which
                to select a babysitter. Don't pay a small fortune to access a huge
                list of mediocre resumes. Join DateNight and have 3 interviews
                in 10 minutes. Odds are - you'll love all 3 candidates.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="table-3" class="table-display">
                <img src="images/search_transparent.png" alt="">
                <h1 class="blue-title">Safer for Everyone</h1>
                <p class="blue-text"> Parents want to decide who is babysitting for their kids.
                With us, you'll have all the necessary elements they need to make
                an informed decision on childcare - an interview, reference info and
                relevant babysitter experience. Babysitters are people's kids, too.
                Ws protect babyistter safety by not revealing their full identity
                online until they have agreed to meet a family. Everyone deserves to be safe.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>


    .info-table {
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: 'Raleway', helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .table-display {
        display: table-cell;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 1em;
        width: 33.3%;
    }

    img {
        width: 6em;
        height: 6em;
    }

    #table-2 {
        background-color: #000039;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        text-align: justify;
    }

    .white-title, .white-text {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .blue-title, .blue-text {
        color: #000039;
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .table-display {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .info-table {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 3em;
        }

        p {
            text-align: justify;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Isn't it your `padding: 3em;`?

Comment: You need to CSS reset. Else depending on your browser you might get random behavior. On Chrome - `body { margin: 8px; }`

Comment: First you might need to add a css reset file, like the one [here. Reset CSS file example](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). After this is done, if necessary check your box sizing. Check [these](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWrZWR) changes I made in your example

Comment: @nicolas I wanted the 3em to be all around anyway, which was fine, but there seemed to be some extra space beyond that, which I dealt with thanks following Michael Coker's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an element `.table-display` that has horizontal padding and `width: 100%` and it's using the standard "content-box" box-model so that pushes the width to 100% + padding, and that extra width pushes to the right side.

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to that element to contain the padding inside of the specified width. You can add it anywhere. Personally, I use `*, *:after, *:before { box-sizing: border-box; }`, but you could also just add it to your media query where you specify `width: 100%`.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .table-display {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

}
```